# Trying to get position in barycentric , I think?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Alright, so I'm trying to achieve whats in this image:
[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28109593/dotsexample.png]

I believe this would be a barycentric coord system, but where the X always equals 1? Basically I need it to only increase/decrease when I move towards/away from the highest point in my triangle. This is the code I got for it so far (Note I'm using the LWJGL library in java).

```
public float getDist( Vector3f p, Vector3f a, Vector3f b, Vector3f c )
   {
       Vector3f v0 = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
       Vector3f.sub( c, a, v0 );
       Vector3f v1 = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
       Vector3f.sub( b, a, v1);
       Vector3f v2 = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
       Vector3f.sub( p, a, v2 );

       float dot00 = Vector3f.dot(v0, v0);
       float dot01 = Vector3f.dot(v0, v1);
       float dot02 = Vector3f.dot(v0, v2);
       float dot11 = Vector3f.dot(v1, v1);
       float dot12 = Vector3f.dot(v1, v2);

       float inverse = 1.0f / (dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01);
       float u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * inverse;
       float v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * inverse;

       if((u >= 0) && (v >= 0) && (u + v <= 1)) return (float) (Math.sin(u) * Math.cos(v));
       else return 0;
   }
```

edit: I guess what I'm asking is: Is there a way to get the distance that a point inside a triangle has travailed from the lowest point the triangle has in space where 1 would be the highest point on the triangle (mosty far away from the lowist) without taking it's deviating vector into account? I.E. notice that the two red dots on the image have the same coords even though they have different dists from the top's x?

Edit2: [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28109593/axisexample.png]

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate a little more about your question? I don't understand the requirement, are you trying to detect if a point lies in the edge of the triangle, or inside?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It's not clear what you want to do, or what you're having trouble with, or what your actual question is.

Comment: Um, *why* are the 2 red dots supposed to have the same coordinates?  What do you mean by "deviating vector"?  Your original question says "I'm trying to achieve what's in this image", but your image isn't self-explanatory.  Until you supply some context, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: The two red dots are suppose to have the same coords cause thats how I need them. "deviating" means the blue one in the new image I.E. on a straight (A triangle whose vector top to bottom has no  change in the X value) triangle it'd be the X axis, but this axis will rotate with the triangle to basically be the axis that is +/-90 degrees from the directional axis of the triangle.

Comment: Yes, I added a new image, should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying: you have a triangle (`abc`) in 3D coordinates, and you want to evaluate the elevation of a fourth point (`p`) above one edge, proportionate to its opposite point:

```
b  --------------- 1.0
|\
| \
| p\ ------------- (result)
|   \
a----c  ---------- 0.0
```

You are correct in that this result is one of three barycentric coordinates for a point on the triangle.

I recommend something like the following:

- find the normal of the plane of the triangle: `vABC = cross(c-a, b-a)`
- find a normal perpendicular to `vABC` and `ac`: `vPerpAC = cross(c-a, vABC)`
- evaluate the vector `ab` with respect to it:  `sAB = dot(vPerpAC, b-a)`
- evaluate your target point:  `sAP = dot(vPerpAC, p-a)`
- your final result is the ratio of these last two evaluations:  `return sAP / sAB`

This should be robust against points that aren't actually on the triangle:  they are effectively projected perpendicularly onto the `abc` plane.

---

Note that, if you know `abc` beforehand, you can precalculate the following values:

- the scaled normal: `vScaled = vPerpAC / sAB`
- the scaled offset: `sScaled = dot(vScaled, a)`

and compute the result of a series of points `p` more efficiently:

- `return dot(vScaled, p) - sScaled`

This effectively precomputes an oriented plane, pre-scaled to directly provide the desired result.

Comment: Very good answer, upvoted, but it's not working. I think it actually has to be in 2d so the distance formula doesn't take into account the Y difference. Know of a easy way to convert this answer to 2d?

Comment: If you want to simply drop the Y coordinate:  instead of the double cross-product, compute perpendicular 2d vector `vPerpAC = (c.z-a.z, a.x-c.x)`.  Use it with 2d `dot()` products on 2d vectors `(b-a) = (b.x-a.x, b.z-a.z)` and `(p-a) = (p.x-a.x, p.z-a.z)`.